# django-tinymce in django-admin popup window display blank

Tags: tinymce, django-tinymce

I followed django-tinymce document configuration step by step and finally can see tinymce editor in django-admin pages.

But when I click Image button, the popup window is blank. And the title of popup window is '{#advanced_dlg.image_title}' like something wrong about parse.

The HTML view button is the same.

I know that 'document.domain' may solve it, but I set 'document.domain' is no help to above.

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is the associated tinymce plugin activated in your tinymce config?

`{#advanced_dlg.image_title}` looks like the plugin (and the language files) have not been loaded.

You amy use Firebug or any other developer web tool with a console and type in the following to find out which plugins have been loaded:

```
tinymce.editors[0].plugins
```

Comment: tinymce.editors[0].plugins
Object
advhr: b.create.f.(anonymous function)
advimage: b.create.f.(anonymous function)
advlink: b.create.f.(anonymous function)
contextmenu: b.create.f.(anonymous function)
emotions: b.create.f.(anonymous function)
fullscreen: b.create.f.(anonymous function)
iespell: b.create.f.(anonymous function)
insertdatetime: b.create.f.(anonymous function)
media: b.create.f.(anonymous function)
preview: b.create.f.(anonymous function)
print: b.create.f.(anonymous function)
......   It seems have been loading plugins

Comment: yes, i do not know the name of the plugin you were reffering to, but i guess it is advimage